# Rotativa PDF MVC3 Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, rotativa

Am using [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa) to create pdfs in my mvc4 application. Problem is how do i get display page numbers on the pdfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to leverage page footer options on wkhtmltopdf by adding a CustomSwitches property to Rotativa *AsPdf.
Take a look at http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html

Comment: up voted for including a link to the docs in your answer. Nice touch.

Comment: link appears broken https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Answer (score 7):

This code will give you a page number at the center of the footer.

```
return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf()
{
    CustomSwitches = "--page-offset 0 --footer-center [page] --footer-font-size 8"
}
```

Use --page-offset option to set the starting page number. 
Set the page offset to 0 and the page number will start at 1 (This is also the default option).
Font size can be controlled by specifying the --footer-font-size option.

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all do i need something on the page like a footer section